# jQuery UI Dialog Reuse Behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

Each time the onchange() event fires, the dialog recursively nests itself inside a new layer.  How can I avoid this behavior. Not version specific.

http://jsfiddle.net/rqLqtuj5/2/

```
<input type=text onchange="popDialog(this)" value="test">
<div style="display:none">
    <p>dialog box</p>
<div>

function popDialog(obj) {
$('div')
    .dialog({
    buttons: {
        'Close': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I fix this using the `empty()` command to clean the div, example:

```js
function popDialog(obj) {
    $('div').empty();
    $('div').dialog({
        buttons: {
            'Close': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p>Change the value in the text box and hit tab ...close the dialog and do it again, and again</p>
<input type=text onchange="popDialog(this)" value="test">
<div style="display:none">
    <p>dialog box</p>
<div>
```

This way is even better: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/nemenijime/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: This is going to empty every single `div` on the page each time it opens a dialog. Potentially deleting meaningful content.

Comment: The Brant was correct you need to use the open method of dialog

Comment: Yeah, IRL I'm using a jQuery selector to locate the target `<div>` and the selector is specific enough '`$(obj).parent().siblings('td.dialog-change-reason')`' that I'm only calling `.empty()` on that target.  Works great - thanx

Comment: Neville. if you put an id into your div and use that to select is gonna be more faster. other thing, you can instance the dialog into a var them when have the onchange you can do `$("selector").dialog("open");" `instead of empty, have one example in my answer

Comment: Gabriel thank you for the additional example.  But in my actual project the markup is generated inside `<ItemTemplate>` of an `<asp:repeater>` So when a user changes data row values the dialog prompts the user to provide a comment.  So the selector search must be relative so `.dialog()` is called to display the current table row `<input>` comment box.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you call `.dialog()` on the general `div` selector (i.e., the first time you change the input field), jQuery UI goes and appends to the DOM a `div` that is a sibling to your `input` element. Now, change the input field again, and jQuery UI searches for a `div` to call `.dialog()` on, and finds the `div` that it created after the first call and makes that into a dialog box. This process continues ad infinitum, as you can probably see.

The solution is to assign a specific class or id to the `div` on which you wish to call `.dialog()`, and then use that class or id as the selector when you call `.dialog()`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  My code snippet is an oversimplification of the actual use - in my app I'm using a jQuery selector to locate `<div>` by class (I also tried id) and the behavior continued ...perhaps its duplicating an exact copy of the `<div>` ...anyway @brant-olsen solution fixed it in all instances.  Thanx